# Laravel 9 Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-9

api.php file:-

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/


Route::post('login', [UserController::class,'login']);

Route::prefix('user')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->controller(UserController::class)->group(function () {

   Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

   Route::post('/create','create'); 



});
```

Result of php artisan route:list :-

```
POST       api/login .................................................. generated::ZbCPv6PYuv5EbuXE › UserController@login
  POST       api/user/create ........................................... generated::FVy5Q2BuwMm8p22P › UserController@create
  GET|HEAD   api/user/user .................................................... generated::6FyVEOXSKZ88144C › UserController
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ......................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

Kernel.php file:-

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
             \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

The solution i tried :-

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to access a route by it's name. You may need to name you route:

```
Route::post('login', [UserController::class,'login'])->name('login');
```

Answer (score 1):

**naming route will solve this issues , so name it**

`->name('login')` also check `get` or `post`.i create both route you may use according to your requirements.
GET ROUTE:

`Route::get('/login', [UserController::class,'login'])->name('login');`

POST ROUTE:

`Route::post('/login', [UserController::class,'login'])->name('login');`

Comment: I've added ->name('login') now it throw another error The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST. in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tawjeeh/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 122

Comment: In the error , its referring to the route('login') in Authenticate file, which it look for login in web.php routes not api "app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php(18): route('login')" is there any configuration i should do to tell laravel when i use middleware auth:sanctum to check the sanctum auth class instead of web auth "Authenticate.php"

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding

```
Accept application/json
```

to the Postman header, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71287554/2873860)

Answer (score 0):

You have it already:
"api/login"
If you wish to be accessed without "api" prefix move it to web.php file.

Comment: Can you explain how can i do this ?